# Raspberry Pi Error: AttributeError: module 'l293d.driver' has no attribute to 'motor'

Tags: pi-2, python-3, dc-motor

So, I am trying to use my RPi model 2B to control a DC motor with an l293d controller.  I have moved onto the python3 script and imported the 'l293d' module.  Here is my code...

```
import l293d.driver as l293d
motor1 = l293d.motor(22,18,16)
for i in range(200):
    motor1.clockwise()
l293d.cleanup()
```

and the error that it returns is...

```
AttributeError: module 'l293.driver' has no attribute 'motor'
```

Can someone please explain why this error is occurring.  Thanks.

Comment: Not Pi specific.  The message is quite explicit.  module 'l293.driver' has no attribute 'motor'.  That means there is nothing called motor in the module l293d.driver (whatever that is).

Comment: Did you create a file named l283d.py yourself? That would confuse Python

Comment: No, the file is called 'motor.py', but it is in python3.  Is this a module for python2 only?

Answer (score 3):

If you read the [documentation](http://l293d.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide/python-scripts/), there are two mistakes in  your code. First, just use `import l293d`. Second, use `motor1 = l293d.DC(22, 18, 16)`

There isn't a motor attribute, but there is a DC attribute for DC motors.

This runs on my system.

```
jay@gotham:~/python$ python3 test.py
[l293d]: Can't import RPi.GPIO; test mode has been enabled:
http://l293d.rtfd.io/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/#test-mode
[l293d]: spinning clockwise motor at BOARD pins [22, 18 and 16]
[l293d]: spinning clockwise motor at BOARD pins [22, 18 and 16]

(... Many repetitions of the above line removed ...)

[l293d]: Cleanup not needed when test_mode is enabled.
jay@gotham:~/python$
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [documentation page for the l293d Python library](http://l293d.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide/python-scripts/), you've used syntax that's incorrect. The docs suggest this may work:

```
import l293d  
motor1 = l293d.DC(22, 18, 16)
```

then the rest of your code.

Comment: @NomadMaker called out a mistake in my answer; +1 for him :) I'm going to edit my answer just to eliminate a potential source of confusion.